# Como compilar fontes em diferentes pastas usando Makefile?

Tags: c++, build, make

Preciso compilar arquivos `.cpp`, gerando os respectivos `.o`, mas cada arquivo está em um diretório diferente.

Por exemplo, tenho duas pastas:

- `build`: onde deveria ficar os arquivos compilados `.o`
- `src`: onde estão os arquivos fontes `.cpp`

Meu objetivo é fazer com que o Make compile (ou recompile) os arquivos fonte que foram modificados e bote os arquivos compilados `.o` no diretório `build`. O problema é que os arquivos `.cpp` estão em diferentes sub-diretórios.

Estou utilizando o Windows como sistema operacional.

Meu Makefile:

```makefile
APP_NAME = uni.exe
BUILD_PATH = build

CC = g++
CPP_VERSION = -std=c++20
SOURCE = \
    main.cpp \
    src/color/parser/colorParser.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/filesystemHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/listHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/literalHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/numberTypeDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/objectHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/regexHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/systemHelpDef.cpp \
    src/commands/definition/typeHelpDef.cpp \
    src/filesystem/formating/fileFormating.cpp \
    src/filesystem/handle/file.cpp \
    src/instream/input/instream.cpp \
    src/instream/scanner/instreamScanner.cpp \
    src/parser/processing/token/tokenProcessing.cpp \
    src/path/handler/pathHandler.cpp \
    src/path/scanner/pathScanner.cpp \
    src/system/exception/exceptionRef.cpp \
    src/system/global/global.cpp \
    src/system/system.cpp \
    src/utilities/cmdUtil.cpp \
    src/utilities/typeUtil.cpp 



OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/, $(notdir $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)))


.PHONY: build

# procura pelos arquivos objeto em "build/"
# se o arquivo não existir, então compile-o a partir de
# seu arquivo fonte correspondente. 

# exemplo: build/colorParser.o = src/color/parser/colorParser.cpp

build: $(OBJECTS)


# regra que deveria criar um arquivo objeto em "build/" a partir
# de um arquivo fonte correspondente de "%.o"
.SILENT:
%.o:
    echo $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, adicione a variável `VPATH`:

```bash
VPATH:=$(shell find src -type d)
```

O comando `find src -type d` retorna todos os diretórios dentro da pasta `src`. E o `VPATH`, segundo a [documentação](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html), indica a lista de diretórios que o `make` usa para procurar os arquivos. Sendo assim, a linha acima está indicando para procurar em qualquer sub-diretório dentro de `src`.

Se for no Windows, pode trocar o comando para `cmd dir src\* /AD /S`, ou ainda usar `$(sort $(dir $(wildcard src/*/ src/*/*/)))` para uma solução mais portável - o problema é que esta precisa de cada subnível explicitamente (por exemplo, se quisesse também o terceiro subnível, teria que adicionar `src/*/*/*/`).

---

Depois, basta incluir os comandos para gerar os arquivos `.o`, e também o comando que junta-os no executável final:

```bash
$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPP_VERSION) -c -o $@ $<

build: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CPP_VERSION) $(OBJECTS) -o $(APP_NAME)
```

Agora é só rodar `make build` e pronto.

---

Opcionalmente, pode incluir a opção para limpar tudo:

```bash
clean:
    rm -f $(BUILD_PATH)/*.o $(APP_NAME)
```

Para mais informações, consulte a [documentação](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/).

Comment: Seu exemplo de código parece funcionar, mas esqueci de mencionar que estou utilizando o sistema operacional Windows ＞﹏＜ (desculpa aí), então acho que o "shell find" não vai funcionar. Existe algum comando de CMD do Windows ou do Make que tem uma funcionalidade semelhante?

Comment: @MarvinMarjan Se não me engano, seria `cmd dir src\* /AD /S`. Ou, usando funções do `make`, seria `$(sort $(dir $(wildcard src/*/ src/*/*/)))` (mas é mais chato porque precisa incluir um `src/*/` para cada subnível - por exemplo, se tiver 3 subníveis, tem que adicionar `src/*/*/*/`, bem mais chato)

Comment: Funcionou mano!! valeu mesmo.